Error: apiRequestContext.get: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Playwright
I'm trying to execute this API test:
import { test } from "@playwright/test";

test("health check request", async ({ request }) => {
  await request.get(`<my-url>`);
});

When I execute this test I'm getting Error: apiRequestContext.get: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <my-url> error.
Full Error Message:
Error: apiRequestContext.get: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <my-url>
Call log:
  - → GET <my-url>
  -   user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.6533.17 Safari/537.36
  -   accept: /
  -   accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br


    at tests\example.spec.ts:4:17

I've tried with demo apps and then the test ran just fine, so my machine probably OK.
From what I've found about this error message it looks like node related error, but as I've already mentioned, I've tested with other demo API apps and no error occur.

Please share <my-url>. Without that, the problem isn't reproducible. You post a lot of canonicals, and I understand you're trying to help the community, but these questions need to follow the rules of the site and be reproducible and answerable by someone besides yourself, or they're off-topic. Thanks.

OK, I understand. In this case though, you'll need to be authorized to access both the URL and PROXY addresses. and I've posted that because everyone who faces this error wouldn't waste so much time as I have by looking for a solution.

I understand you're trying to help, but we still need reproductions. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND can be caused by other causes than failing to add a proxy. This thread would devolve into a big dump of "in my case, the problem was ". Those questions/threads are sometimes helpful for desperate people fishing for answers, but generally off-topic. Self-answered questions still need to be reproducible and generally answerable.

OK, thanks for the explanation, I'll search for a reproducable code.

I've finally found the problem, this particular application needs to be access via proxy.
So as shown in Playwright docs, I've added the proxy address to playwright.config like so:
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: "./tests",

  use: {
    proxy: {
      server: "<proxy_address>",
      username: '<user_name>',
      password: '<password>',
    },
  },

  projects: [{ name: "chromium" }],
});

(username and password are optional)
